# PHP imagefttext (imagettftext) not displaying anything

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

I'm almost positive that there is a stupid reason this is not working, but I just can't figure this one out.  I'm just trying to print out some text as a graphic with imagettftext, but I can't get the words to display.  This is on a GoDaddy server, so I don't control everything, but here are the specs from phpinfo():

- PHP Version 5.2.14
- --with-gd' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr/bin/libpng-config' '--enable-gd-native-ttf'
- GD Support enabled
- GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
- FreeType Support enabled
- FreeType Linkage with freetype
- FreeType Version 2.2.1

Here is the code I'm using.  Nothing fancy or strange.

```
$width = 270;
$height = 25;
$image = imageCreate($width, $height);
$white = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'verdana.ttf';
imagefttext($image, 16, 0, 0, 0, $black, $font, 'TESTING TEXT');
header("Content-type:  image/gif");
imageGIF($image);
```

I've tried changing the font name different ways:

```
$font = './verdana.ttf';
$font = dirname(__FILE__).'/verdana.ttf';
```

I've tried using PNG instead of GIF, I've tried using imagefttext() and imagettftext(), I've tried displaying errors, but it doesn't show any errors, just a blank screen.  Any ideas?  It's gotta be something so stupid...

Comment: To all who come here from the search engines: please pay attention to the answer by @Mark Lalor below, because I regret I didn't. That was my issue exactly: I had to set `imagettftext($image, 20, 20, 20, 20, $black, $font, 'TESTING TEXT');` to start seeing a tiny bit of the text and then I took it from there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it **(It hurt my head for a while considering I'm an expert on this...)**

The mistake was that the **Y position** has to have an **offeset** of the **font size** so it should look like this

```
<?php
$width = 270;
$height = 25;
$image = imageCreate($width, $height);
$white = imageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'verdana.ttf';
imagettftext($image, 16, 0, 0, 16, $black, $font, 'TESTING TEXT');
header("Content-type:  image/gif");
imageGIF($image);
?>
```

Comment: Wow, it was something stupid.  The Y position is the bottom of the text, not the top.  Ugh.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Oops, looks like Jatt's answer came before yours.  I'm going to switch the accepted answer to his.  Thanks again, though.

Comment: OK, I can't read correctly.  Switching the answer back to yours.  Sheesh.

Comment: Sincerely you made me laugh and saved me from the same headache haha !

Comment: This saved me!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you spelled `imagettftext` wrong?

Comment: imagettftext() and imagefttext() are two different functions.  Thanks for trying to help, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$font = "verdana.ttf";
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(270, 25)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$backg = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $backg);
$color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0,0,0);
ImageTTFText($im,16,0,0,16, $color,$font,'hello');
header ('Content-type: image/gif');
ImageGIF($im);
ImageDestroy($im);
```

try this ... font in the same folder

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Stinking Y coordinate is the bottom of the text, not the top, so I was displaying the text off the top of the graphic.  Sheesh.

Comment: I accepted Mark's answer since it came a couple minutes before yours.  Thanks a lot though.